# Date picker issue - Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to the scripting languages, I need help to resolve this issue. The bootstrap date picker resets the field when I choose the same date by using the date picker icon.

```
$('#from_date .input-daterange').datepicker({
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  format: "dd-M-yyyy",
  endDate: '+0d',
  clearBtn: true,
  forceParse: false,
  autoclose: true,
});
```

My HTML line of code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" style="margin-left: -5px;  width: 99px;" class="form-control" id="fromdate" 
name="quote-issue-date-start" placeholder="From date" data-bind="value:fromDate"  />
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</span>
```

The textbox gets cleared when I again choose the date from the datepicker.

Comment: I reckon this shouldn't be working at all, not even showing a datepicker. You have no element with id from_date or class input-daterange

Comment: div class="form-group" id="quote-issue-date">
                                                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="col-sm-6" id="dt-container">
                                    <div class="input-append input-group date" data-bind="validationElement: fromDate">

                                        <input type="text" style="margin-left: -5px;  width: 99px;" class="form-control" id="fromdate" name="from-date-start" placeholder="From date" data-bind="value:fromDate"  /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>

Comment: I have mentioned the Id in the <div> tag.. wasn't it correct? I can choose the date from the datepicker

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o9u6curd/

Answer (score 0):

Many things look wrong:

1. You try to select an element which does not exist: `$('#from_date` - the id in your markup is `fromdate` (withouth the underscore)
2. In your selector `$('#from_date .input-daterange')` you try to select `.input-daterange` inside `#from_date` - if `#from_date` is an `<input>` element it cant have children, so the selector should be `$('#from_date.input-daterange')` (if the input would actually have that class)
3. You have a syntax error:

   `autoclose: true, });`

The `,` is false here.

Comment: dont put that in the comments - nobody can read this. create a jsfiddle

Comment: dont put that in the comments - nobody can read this. create a jsfiddle

Comment: this is not how you will be helped here, show at least a little effort. people wont do all the work for you: clean up your code, read my answer and post your updated code in a new fiddle.